LiDAR DTM slope slope analysis with a twist. Calculate elevation changes of at least 10 feet within horizontal distance of 25 feet
I have raster DTM image of LiDAR data, mapped to Washington state plane north (US survey feet), where each pixel represents an elevation value in feet.
Generating a "slope map" which shows all of the areas with slopes equal to or greater than 40% is easy enough.
However, what I really want to generate is a map that shows slopes with an average incline of 40 percent or more, that also have an elevation of change of at least 10 feet within a horizontal distance of 25 feet. For the purpose of this definition, a slope area is where the ground surface drops (or rises) 10 feet or more vertically within a horizontal distance of 25 feet.
Currently I am generating a slope map, then generating 10 foot contours, and manually identifying areas that meet the criteria. There has to be a better way, but my QGIS skills are not up to the task. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

One basic approach would be to separately run a Maximum Filter and a Minimum Filter with a size of 25 feet, or radius of half that. This will give you two new rasters.
Then subtract the output of the Minimum Filter from the output of the Maximum Filter (use Raster Calculator). Anywhere where this final result is greater than 10 feet should meet your elevation change criterion.
You can then combine this raster with your slope > 40% raster to get your overall slope map. Use Raster Calculator again for this step.
For example: Slope map (darker areas steeper)

Difference (lighter areas steeper)

Final slope map (white = true, black = false):

The basic toolbox does not have Max/Min Filters, but Whitebox Tools and SAGA have equivalents.
For Whitebox Tools they are called Maximum Filter and Minimum Filter.
For SAGA, use Rank Filter with 100% (for Maximum Filter) and 0% (for Minimum Filter).
Install:

Whitebox Tools: https://www.whiteboxgeo.com/download-whiteboxtools/
Whitebox Tools Processing Provider: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/wbt_for_qgis/
SAGA GIS: https://saga-gis.sourceforge.io/en/index.html
SAGA GIS Processing Provider: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/processing_saga_nextgen/


Thank you so much. I was able to accomplish the task based on your suggestions and the additional SAGA tool set.
